# INSERT time on very large database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, load

Roughly, on a high-end server, how long would it take for an insert query to insert 2million records of 7 fields, into an existing, well indexed database of 8million records of 7 fields?

Im amateur at best when it comes to large databases, and really have no concept of time scale for these things at all. I'd appreciate any explanations or considerations you may provide.

Server:

- 16gigs RAM, 4x 2.4GHz
- mySQL, phpMyadmin, ubuntu 10, apache2

EDIT:

Sorry to cause such offence with this question, I really am just learning.

Proposed table set-up as an example:

**Table1**

```
subscribersNew 
  subEmail (varchar: 255), 
  subName (varchar: 32), 
  subDob (timestamp), 
  subGender (varchar: 1),
  subRegDate (timestamp), 
  subEmailList (int: 2), 
  subThirdParties (bool)
```

**Table2**

```
subscribers
  subEmail (varchar: 255), 
  subName (varchar: 32), 
  subDob (timestamp), 
  subGender (varchar: 1),
  subRegDate (timestamp), 
  subEmailList (int: 2), 
  subThirdParties (bool)
```

Indexed columns: `subEmail`

Query:

```
INSERT INTO subscribers 
select * from subscribersNew
left outer join subscribers
    on subscribersNew.subEmail = subscribers.subEmail
where subscribers.subEmail is null;
```

Comment: sorry for offending you marc_s, ill add the details for you.

Comment: You're not offending me - I'm just trying to get all the possibly relevant information, so someone can actually answer your question ... now with the columns and their datatype, one can get a solid understanding of what we're dealing with - so now one can estimate how much data we're talking about, and an answer becomes possible ...

Comment: There are just so many many many things that can affect performance by many orders of magnitude. How heavily indexed is the table?(affects insert performance). Any triggers? Tons of DBMS specific items: is table partitioned? is table logging or not? Are indexes logging or not? Can you bypass the db's buffer cache? e.g. Oracle's direct path load/+APPEND hint. What is the load on the machine? Are other users hitting this table at the same time? You really have to try it on a test instance to get a rough idea of the baseline time involved.

Answer (score 0):

This is not something we can't answer. 
SQL Server is very I/O bound so it depends on your HDD/SSD hardware and network, the indexes on the table, the data you are inserting and the columns you are inserting into.

Comment: Who says he's using SQL Server??

Comment: True but I suppose the same applies for any relational database.

Comment: Thats my mistake then, sorry for asking. Im trying to get an understanding of load times these sort of servers would expect to have when such queries are performed.

Comment: As with anything its best to test it before trying to prematurely optimse.